# How to deploy SAP Spartacus PWA to app stores

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We are currently working on a new PWA mobile app using the SAP Spartacus framework, and we would like to package and upload this new mobile app to the Google and Apple app stores. I've found online documentation for using Bubblewrap for deploying PWAs to the Google play store and PWABuilder for deploying PWAs to the Apple app store, but I have not found anything online specifically for Spartacus PWAs.

I have not yet attempted to deploy to either of these stores using either of the packages mentioned (Bubblewrap or PWABuilder), but I'm assuming from experience that the process for packaging and deploying a Spartacus PWA will be more complicated than a simple PWA.

Has anyone done this already and can share tips/tricks on how to make this happen? Is anyone aware of online resources to help make this happen?